# Restoring Google Cloud Datastore Backup Succeeds, But No Data Restored

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I created a database of a few TBs of data, which was initially uploaded to Google Datastore. A few months ago we decided to take this down via a backup and delete the entities to save on storage costs as it wasn't needed.

We've decided to restore the dataset, which required me to re-upload the dataset from a local hard drive. Which was a success. And when I goto the Datastore admin screen I am able to successfully run the restore command.

[Datastore Operation Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdHTE.png)

However no actual data gets restored. The operation completes but no data is loaded into datastore.

[Datastore Operation Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Bodo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Without any logs it's hard to help here.  However, you may try doing your import through the [Managed Import/Export service](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities).  That may provide you with better status than the DatastoreAdmin module.